# Acitivity Navigation from resumed state to the activity that was paused

Tags: java, android

I want to ask  when I pause the acitivity X I want to navigate to homepage. Which I have done using intent. Then I want to enter the user details to log in and then resume the same activity which I have paused . I have learned about get intent

Comment: why do you want to pause the activity rather than removing it from stack?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that what you want to do is:

1. Do not finish() the main activity (as you seem to imply you currently do)
2. Start the login activity with startActivityForResult()
3. In the login activity set the return value depending on the outcome (successful or not and maybe some extra details of the permission and user profile depending on your needs)
4. in the main activity use the onActivityResult to check if the login was successful